# Interpreting HTML Tags in Javascript String Literal

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I make an AJAX call that gives me a string within a JSON object containing text formatted like this:

```
Your girl was in Berkeley with a communist reader. <br> Mine was entombed within boombox and walkman. <br> I was a hoarder, but girl, that was back then. <br> The gloves are off, the wisdom teeth are out. <br> What you on about? <br> I can feel it in my bones. <br> I can feel it in my bones. <br> I'm stronger now, I'm ready for the house. <br> Such a modest mouse. <br> I can't do this alone.
```

I use this string to populate a div on my webpage, such that it appears like this:

```
<div class="lyrics-container>{{ the text in the JSON string }} </div>
```

However, when populating the div with that text, I get the exact string, meaning that the `<br>`s show up as text. I want them to actually perform their function and break the line. Is there a way to coerce the browser into interpreting HTML within a string?

I'm using Angular to grab the data and populate the div if that makes any difference.

Comment: How do you set the json object to your div ? did you try innerHTML ?

Comment: You are missing a quote on your div class ---- `"` after lyrics-container but before `>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not straight forward. You need to use `ngBindHtml`.

#### Controller

```
$scope.content = "<b>this is bold content</b>";
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>
```

You'll need the following module:

http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular-sanitize.js

Be sure to declare `ngSanitize` as a module dependancy, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ["ngSanitize"]);
```

Comment: dont put {{}} in ng-bind-html, since it is an expression

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ng-bind-html-unsafe](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe).

```
<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="content"></span>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rRZnH/)**</kbd>